# Android ListPreference returns wrong value

Tags: android, android-layout, sharedpreferences, android-resources, listpreference

When I try to read the default value of my "sync_frequency" in the SharedPreferences it returns 30 but should 300000.

My resources:

```
<resources>
      <string name="pref_title_sync_frequency">Intervall</string>
<string-array name="pref_sync_frequency_titles">
    <item>5 min.</item>
    <item>10 min.</item>
    <item>15 min.</item>
    <item>20 min.</item>
    <item>30 min.</item>
    <item>60 min.</item>
    <item>Nimals</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="pref_sync_frequency_values">
    <item>300000</item>
    <item>600000</item>
    <item>900000</item>
    <item>1200000</item>
    <item>1800000</item>
    <item>3600000</item>
    <item>-1</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

My Preference page:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="300000"
    android:entries="@array/pref_sync_frequency_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_sync_frequency_values"
    android:key="sync_frequency"
    android:negativeButtonText="@null"
    android:positiveButtonText="@null"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_sync_frequency" />


<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:dependency="sync_frequency"
    android:key="sync_appoint_only_on_wifi"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_on_wifi_appo" />

<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="true"
    android:dependency="sync_frequency"
    android:key="sync_feed_only_on_wifi"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_on_wifi_feed" />
```

The way I try to get the value:

```
    public int syncIntervall(){
    SharedPreferences spr = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
    return Integer.valueOf(spr.getString("sync_frequency", "300000"));
}
```

Returns 30;

Comment: That's weird, innit... Can you debug to see what `spr` contains exactly?

Comment: Yea, its an SharedPreferences object ;) and in the containing mMap object the value is also 30.

Comment: Ahhh, got it its just an SPF(Stupid Programmer Failure) i had do delete the preference cache on my phone.

Comment: Haha there's no such thing as SPF. 20% of programming is writing code, the rest 80% being debugging and searching for the error ;)

Comment: Yea, but it was so obvious and it a takes month to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the applications Preference cache does not reset itself by installing an new version of the app. I had to uninstall the app by hand.